# PHP, JS & AJAX file browser doesn't show subfolders

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

So for my internship i have to make a file browser to view files from a remote server. My problem is that it doesn't show the subfolders! But it does show the parent folder. For example: It does show the folder "Demo" but not the subfolders in "Demo". Personally, i think it's a JS problem. This only happens when i use a remote server path. My code works just fine when the folder is locally on the server. So my question is: can anybody see what i did wrong? I just can't find the issue :(

PHP:`

```
<?php

$dir = '\\\\zwosvr007\\SF Centraal\\Unica Online - Klant Portaal\\';
//$dir = 'handleidingen';
// $dir = 'handleidingen';


// Run the recursive function

$response = scan($dir);




// This function scans the files folder recursively, and builds a large array

function scan($dir)
{

    $files = array();

    // Is there actually such a folder/file?


        foreach (glob($dir . "*", GLOB_BRACE) as $f) {
            if (is_readable($f)) {
                if (!$f || $f[0] == '.') {
                    continue; // Ignore hidden files
                }


                if (is_dir($f)) {


                    // The path is a folder

                    $files[] = array(
                        "name" => str_replace($dir, "", $f),
                        "type" => "folder",
                        "path" => $f,
                        "items" =>  scansub($f) // Recursively get the contents of the folder
                    );
                } else {

                    // It is a file

                    $files[] = array(
                        "name" => str_replace($dir, "", $f),
                        "type" => "file",
                        "path" => $f,
                        //"size" => filesize($dir . '/' . $f) // Gets the size of this file
                        "size" => filesize($f) // Gets the size of this file
                    );
                }
            }
            else{
//                  echo fileperms("\\\\zwoapp029\\DOSSIER\\");
//                  echo "<br>";
            }

        }





    return $files;
}

function scansub($f){


    $files = array();



                foreach (scandir($f) as $g) {
                    if (!$g || $g[0] == '.') {
                        continue; // Ignore hidden files
                    }


                    if (is_dir($f . '\\' . $g)) {

                        // The path is a folder

                        $files[] = array(
                            "name" => $g,
                            "type" => "folder",
                            "path" => $f . '\\' . $g,
                            "items" => scansub($f . '\\' . $g) // Recursively get the contents of the folder
                        );
                    } else {

                        // It is a file

                        $files[] = array(
                            "name" => $g,
                            "type" => "file",
                            "path" => $f . '\\' . $g,
                            "size" => filesize($f. '\\' . $g) // Gets the size of this file
                            //"size" => filesize($f) // Gets the size of this file
                        );
                    }
                }

    return $files;


}




// Output the directory listing as JSON

header('Content-type: application/json');

echo json_encode(array(
    "name" => $dir,
    "type" => "folder",
    "path" => $dir,
    "items" => $response
));
```

JS:
`

```
    $(function(){

    var filemanager = $('.filemanager'),
        breadcrumbs = $('.breadcrumbs'),
        fileList = filemanager.find('.data');

    // Start by fetching the file data from scan.php with an AJAX request

    $.get('scan.php', function(data) {

        var response = [data],
            currentPath = '',
            breadcrumbsUrls = [];

        var folders = [],
            files = [];

        // This event listener monitors changes on the URL. We use it to
        // capture back/forward navigation in the browser.

        $(window).on('hashchange', function(){

            goto(window.location.hash);

            // We are triggering the event. This will execute 
            // this function on page load, so that we show the correct folder:

        }).trigger('hashchange');


        // Hiding and showing the search box

        filemanager.find('.search').click(function(){

            var search = $(this);

            search.find('span').hide();
            search.find('input[type=search]').show().focus();

        });


        // Listening for keyboard input on the search field.
        // We are using the "input" event which detects cut and paste
        // in addition to keyboard input.

        filemanager.find('input').on('input', function(e){

            folders = [];
            files = [];

            var value = this.value.trim();

            if(value.length) {

                filemanager.addClass('searching');

                // Update the hash on every key stroke
                window.location.hash = 'search=' + value.trim();

            }

            else {

                filemanager.removeClass('searching');
                window.location.hash = encodeURIComponent(currentPath);

            }

        }).on('keyup', function(e){

            // Clicking 'ESC' button triggers focusout and cancels the search

            var search = $(this);

            if(e.keyCode == 27) {

                search.trigger('focusout');

            }

        }).focusout(function(e){

            // Cancel the search

            var search = $(this);

            if(!search.val().trim().length) {

                window.location.hash = encodeURIComponent(currentPath);
                search.hide();
                search.parent().find('span').show();

            }

        });


        // Clicking on folders

        fileList.on('click', 'li.folders', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();


            var nextDir = $(this).find('a.folders').attr('href');

            if(filemanager.hasClass('searching')) {

                // Building the breadcrumbs

                breadcrumbsUrls = generateBreadcrumbs(nextDir);

                filemanager.removeClass('searching');
                filemanager.find('input[type=search]').val('').hide();
                filemanager.find('span').show();
            }
            else {
                breadcrumbsUrls.push(nextDir);
            }

            window.location.hash = encodeURIComponent(nextDir);
            currentPath = nextDir;
        });


        // Clicking on breadcrumbs

        breadcrumbs.on('click', 'a', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var index = breadcrumbs.find('a').index($(this)),
                nextDir = breadcrumbsUrls[index];

            breadcrumbsUrls.length = Number(index);

            window.location.hash = encodeURIComponent(nextDir);

        });


        // Navigates to the given hash (path)

        function goto(hash) {

            hash = decodeURIComponent(hash).slice(1).split('=');

            if (hash.length) {
                var rendered = '';

                // if hash has search in it

                if (hash[0] === 'search') {

                    filemanager.addClass('searching');
                    rendered = searchData(response, hash[1].toLowerCase());

                    if (rendered.length) {
                        currentPath = hash[0];
                        render(rendered);
                    }
                    else {
                        render(rendered);
                    }

                }

                // if hash is some path

                else if (hash[0].trim().length) {

                    rendered = searchByPath(hash[0]);

                    if (rendered.length) {

                        currentPath = hash[0];
                        breadcrumbsUrls = generateBreadcrumbs(hash[0]);
                        render(rendered);

                    }
                    else {
                        currentPath = hash[0];
                        breadcrumbsUrls = generateBreadcrumbs(hash[0]);
                        render(rendered);
                    }

                }

                // if there is no hash

                else {
                    currentPath = data.path;
                    breadcrumbsUrls.push(data.path);
                    render(searchByPath(data.path));
                }
            }
        }

        // Splits a file path and turns it into clickable breadcrumbs

        function generateBreadcrumbs(nextDir){
            var path = nextDir.split('/').slice(0);
            for(var i=1;i<path;i++){
                path[i] = path[i-1]+ '/' +path[i];
            }
            return path;
        }


        // Locates a file by path

        function searchByPath(dir) {
            var path = dir.split('/'),
                demo = response,
                flag = 0;

            for(var i=0;i<path.length;i++){
                for(var j=0;j<demo.length;j++){
                    if(demo[j].name === path[i]){
                        flag = 1;
                        demo = demo[j].items;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            demo = flag ? demo : [];
            return demo;
        }


        // Recursively search through the file tree

        function searchData(data, searchTerms) {

            data.forEach(function(d){
                if(d.type === 'folder') {

                    searchData(d.items,searchTerms);

                    if(d.name.toLowerCase().match(searchTerms)) {
                        folders.push(d);
                    }
                }
                else if(d.type === 'file') {
                    if(d.name.toLowerCase().match(searchTerms)) {
                        files.push(d);
                    }
                }
            });
            return {folders: folders, files: files};
        }


        // Render the HTML for the file manager

        function render(data) {

            var scannedFolders = [],
                scannedFiles = [];


            if(Array.isArray(data)) {

                data.forEach(function (d) {

                    if (d.type === 'folder') {
                        scannedFolders.push(d);
                    }
                    else if (d.type === 'file') {
                        scannedFiles.push(d);
                    }


                });

            }
            else if(typeof data === 'object') {

                scannedFolders = data.folders;
                scannedFiles = data.files;

            }


            // Empty the old result and make the new one

            fileList.empty().hide();

            if(!scannedFolders.length && !scannedFiles.length) {
                filemanager.find('.nothingfound').show();
            }
            else {
                filemanager.find('.nothingfound').hide();
            }

            if(scannedFolders.length) {

                scannedFolders.forEach(function(f) {

                    var itemsLength = f.items.length,
                        name = escapeHTML(f.name),
                        icon = '<span class="icon folder"></span>';

                    if(itemsLength) {
                        icon = '<span class="icon folder full"></span>';
                    }

                    if(itemsLength == 1) {
                        itemsLength += ' item';
                    }
                    else if(itemsLength > 1) {
                        itemsLength += ' items';
                    }
                    else {
                        itemsLength = 'Leeg';
                    }

                    var folder = $('<li class="folders"><a href="'+ f.path +'" title="'+ f.path +'" class="folders">'+icon+'<span class="name">' + name + '</span> <span class="details">' + itemsLength + '</span></a></li>');
                    folder.appendTo(fileList);
                });

            }

            if(scannedFiles.length) {

                scannedFiles.forEach(function(f) {

                    var fileSize = bytesToSize(f.size),
                        name = escapeHTML(f.name),
                        fileType = name.split('.'),
                        icon = '<span class="icon file"></span>';

                    fileType = fileType[fileType.length-1];

                    icon = '<span class="icon file f-'+fileType+'">.'+fileType+'</span>';

                    var file = $('<li class="files"><a href="'+ f.path+'" title="'+ f.path +'" class="files">'+icon+'<span class="name">'+ name +'</span> <span class="details">'+fileSize+'</span></a></li>');
                    file.appendTo(fileList);
                });

            }


            // Generate the breadcrumbs

            var url = '';

            if(filemanager.hasClass('searching')){

                url = '<span>Zoek resultaten: </span>';
                //fileList.removeClass('animated');

            }
            else {

                fileList.addClass('animated');

                breadcrumbsUrls.forEach(function (u, i) {

                    var name = u.split('/');

                    if (i !== breadcrumbsUrls.length - 1) {
                        url += '<a href="'+u+'"><span class="folderName">' + name[name.length-1] + '</span></a> <span class="arrow">→</span> ';
                    }
                    else {
                        url += '<span class="folderName">' + name[name.length-1] + '</span>';
                    }

                });

            }

            breadcrumbs.text('').append(url);


            // Show the generated elements

            fileList.animate({'display':'inline-block'});

        }


        // This function escapes special html characters in names

        function escapeHTML(text) {
            return text.replace(/\&/g,'&amp;').replace(/\</g,'&lt;').replace(/\>/g,'&gt;');
        }


        // Convert file sizes from bytes to human readable units

        function bytesToSize(bytes) {
            var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'];
            if (bytes === 0) return '0 Bytes';
            var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
            return Math.round(bytes / Math.pow(1024, i), 2) + ' ' + sizes[i];
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: If the JS works when PHP echoes a list of local files, then it should work even if PHP echoes a list of remote files (JS should not know where the list came from). However, if you think the issue is in the JS code, then where is that code?

Comment: @wil93 Thank you for your answer! I'll post the JS code in a sec. But is it possible that JS doesn't know how to handle server paths because of the 2 backslashes?